# Selective cell fracture

Tags: particles, physics

Hi i'm trying to make a scene where a bullet shoots itself to the corner of a concrete wall, making the corner pieces fall off. But i'm not sure how to do that without the whole wall breaking.

also should i just use a smoke simulation for the dust that happens when a piece brakes? or is there a much more efficient way with particle systems

Comment: You could always keep some of the bits of the wall a passive rigid body instead of an active so broken pieces still collide with it. Also a mix of low-density smoke sim with some small rubble particles would probably be best.

Comment: i've never played with smoke sims or particle systems, is there a tutorial that you can direct me to so i can learn this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IDBfQnttiE

Comment: thanks, but do you have any ideas on how to make it so that it activates when the debris is hit or something?

Comment: Just set the keyframes of the particles or smoke to be when the bullet hits